# Dependencies not loading visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to run the application with dot net framework 4.1, it was working initially but post restart of my system dependencies are not loading

Here is the image of dependencies:

[image: Image of dependencies]

Comment: using visual studio 2019

Comment: You can [edit] question to add corrections. Looking [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET) you have to have minimum 4.6.1 to be able to use .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: What is your current project, ,net core app or .net framework app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the Individual Components in Visual Studio Installer? Maybe you should install 4.6.1.

[image: Individual Components]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the dependencies I was loading were pointing to a different bitbucket location and I
    had to change the path in the .gitmodule file.